# How create Map<String,List<Long>> java 8 with single stream?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream, long-integer

I have to create a `Map<String,List<Long>>` (possibly with single stream ) with `key= name` of the course , `value= number` of times the course was chosen as first choice (first entry of the list) ,second choice (second entry of the list) ,third choice (third entry of the list) ,
for Example : `Chemstry, List< 4,6,7>`

I tried with this but gives me errors:

```
return courses.values().stream()  
              .collect(groupingBy(Course::getNome,TreeMap::new, collectingAndThen(Course::getchoice, counting()));
```

Comment: Please provide the code that gives you an error including some examples for `Course`s...

Comment: "but gives me errors" — Which errors?

Comment: No code example, no error. How we could help you If you don't help yourself?

Comment: it's not a bad question, but you have formulated it in way that makes in pretty complicated to understand. I'll plus one it, cause I liked it

Answer (score 3):

The grouping and counting is fairly simple, but getting into a list takes a bit more work. Here's one way to do that by `collectingAndThen` streaming the counts:

```
courses.values()
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                Course::getName,
                collectingAndThen(
                        groupingBy(Course::getChoice, counting()),
                        counts -> IntStream.range(0, 3)
                                .mapToObj(i -> counts.getOrDefault(i + 1, 0L))
                                .collect(toList()))))
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/LPCn4D)

EDIT: @Eugene suggests I've misunderstood the requirements. If you want to list all the choices rather than the top three, just replace `3` with `Collections.max(counts.keySet())`.

Comment: what if a course is `A = 1; A = 1, A = 3` the output Map should be `[A = {2, 0, 1}]`, not sure your code does that...

Comment: nice, but still, you assume that there are up to 3 values via `IntStream.range`, I think the correct way would be to compute the max first and work off that

Comment: @Eugene I'm not assuming anything. `getOrDefault()` covers missing values.

Comment: what if you add another entry in your `Map`, like `courses.put(Math.random(), new Course("a", 5));`

Comment: @Eugene Feel free to fork and play with it. Let me know if you find a bug.

Comment: I just did... problem is this `IntStream.range(0, 3)` - you assume that there are 3 possible values all the time and I just gave you an example where this breaks. The correct way to do it would be to compute the `max` first : `int max = counts.keySet().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get(); IntStream.range(0, max)....`

Comment: @Eugene Ok, I think there's a miscommunication here. My understanding was that OP wants only the top 3 choices, not all of them.

Comment: I *highly* doubt this... even if the OP wants the first 3, you are still computing the result wrong... Anyway, it's a good solution and I was working into something close to that, so plus one

Comment: When you use `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max)`, you don’t need add one to all stream elements…

Comment: @Holger That's 6 extra character to save 4... :)

Comment: That’s not saving 4 characters, but one arithmetic instruction performed *per element*.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, if you are willing to do it in two steps:

```
static Map<String, List<Long>> group(Map<?, Course> courses) {

    Map<String, List<Long>> m = courses.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Course::getName,
                            Course::getChoice,
                            Math::max),
                    map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                         Entry::getKey,
                                         e -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(e.getValue(), 0L))))

    ));

    courses.values()
            .forEach(x -> {
                List<Long> l = m.get(x.getName());
                l.set(x.getChoice() - 1, l.get(x.getChoice() - 1) + 1);
            });

    return m;

}
```